# nginx caching $scheme? some keepalive setting?

Tags: ssl, nginx

New site. http goes to drupal. https to a static page. Once I visit the ssl site I cannot get back to the non-ssl one until I clear my cache.

http://donsbox.com
https://donsbox.com

What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This was the culprit: add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200"; (See http://www.chromium.org/sts). Guess I will use a different FQN for SSL, e.g. ssl.donsbox.com